# Windows stop service -> do not error when not started

Tags: windows, windows-services

In a build pipeline for our .NET application, we automated the stopping and starting of our IIS server through

`net stop WAS` and `net start W3SVC`. But there is a problem with the first command. If the service for some reason is not running then stopping it will throw an error

> The Windows Process Activation Service service is not started.

and our pipeline won't continue because of this. We however would like that if the IIS server is already down, this error is not thrown. Hence **how to not raise an error when stopping a non-running service**?

Comment: Check if WAS is already running first. There are a number of different ways you can check this.

Comment: Maybe look at using sc.exe, the exit code of that will be the response from the SCM.  E.g. `sc.exe stop workfolderssvc`. Note this is a stopped service example. `echo %errorlevel%` returns 1062 which is `ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_ACTIVE` or `The service has not been started.`

Comment: As already mentioned, you have to check the service's state and implement the desired actions yourself. [Should I use NET or SC to start/stop/restart our Windows Services?](https://www.coretechnologies.com/blog/windows-services/net-vs-sc/]) outlines some of the issues you may face when calling NET and SC from batch files.